# Is there any way to disable self-refresh of page in ChromeDriver by Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using **ChromeDriver** to navigate to web pages, but the page is getting refreshed itself at short intervals. I don't want that to be happened, because the structure of page will be back to the original after refreshing.

Actually, I used the code `driver.get_log()` to load the logs of the network all the time, and the structure of page determine which of logs driver get. That is why I need that the page don't refresh itself.

link of page:https://www.bet365.com/?lng=10&cb=10581211257#/IP/

Comment: You could capture the inner_html of, say, `html` or `body` elements perhaps? Or disable networking, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh wlan disconnect");`

Comment: Most times I can't even do this even with Chrome Dev tools. Selective self-refresh is the holy grail of reverse engineering a site.

Comment: Post the code, " selenium is used to read the websocket" is too woolly

Comment: What's wrong with `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return window.stop");`?

Comment: I don't delete it.

Comment: Can you link the page? It can be several different redirection method, we need to know which one (js, meta redirect, headers ..)

Comment: It should be js.

Comment: If _the page is getting refreshed itself at short intervals and the structure of page is back to the original after refreshing_ I won't be surprised if  a _JavaScript_ is active and thats too for a purpose. It is still not clear from your question how `driver.get_log()` is getting blocked perhaps you need to update the question with your detailed _usecase_ and code trials

Comment: The structure of page determine which of logs driver get.